# Discord.py command that gives and remove role to the author

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am trying to code a discord bot with python that has a command where u can get/remove a role by typing something like `;me`. So if you already have the role it will remove it and if you do not have the role it will give you the role but it doesnt work. There wouldn't be any errors in the console my bot just wont reply to the command and wont give/remove the role either. Can someone help?

```
@client.command()
async def me(ctx):
  role=client.get_role(123456789)
  if role in ctx.author.roles:
    em1=discord.Embed(description="I have have removed the <@&123456789> role from you.")
    em1.set_author(name=ctx.author.name,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(embed=em1,delete_after=5)
  else:
    em1=discord.Embed(description="I have given you the <@&123456789> role.")
    em1.set_author(name=ctx.author.name,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(embed=em1,delete_after=5)
```

Comment: But you have this line: ```client= commands.Bot(command_prefix=";")```, do you? And make sure your token is correct.

Answer (score 0):

client.get_role(what here?)

i think it should look more like `875098699443892306` be sure what role your giving. to know it - if your on discord:

type @/role to know id of this role

+always make roles in "" , not as-is. dont forget. correct template code (change role id with your role id):

```py
@client.command()
async def me(ctx):
  role=client.get_role("875098699443892306")
  if role in ctx.author.roles:
    em1=discord.Embed(description="I have have removed the <@&123456789> role from you.")
    em1.set_author(name=ctx.author.name,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(embed=em1,delete_after=5)
  else:
    em1=discord.Embed(description="I have given you the <@&123456789> role.")
    em1.set_author(name=ctx.author.name,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(embed=em1,delete_after=5)
```

PS: to avoid things like these - dont run it wirelessly from someone but firstly test on local machine and see error log on your cmd/terminal ;)